# login authentication with .net web server when i click on login button at that time how to show progress bar with login message

Tags: android, webserver, progress-bar

My question is regarding ProgressDialog with Threads for my project. Basically what I want to do in this: 
1) when a user clicks a login button the Activity sends an auth request to the server 
2) while this is being done a ProgressDialog is shown 
3) when the reponse comes I want to dismiss the ProgressDialog and go to the next home page if the login successful and if not than display the invalid login message kind of thing

how can i do ?? please share the code if you can

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to share few things with you.
1. Do you know how to accept answers ?...You have not accpted single answer yet.
2. Why you are again posting the same questions. Your last post was also the same.

Comment: no i donno how to accept answers please tel me...

Comment: Go to your posted questions. Open any of those posts. In that in all answers posted, there in left side you will see a Tick Mark which is not highlighted. If you find that that answer given by other people of SO, solved your problem, just click on that tick mark. I am telling this because the other developers can know whether the answer worked correctly or not. Its beneficial for other users.

Comment: i am not able to see any tick mark on left side :(

Comment: ya thanks kartik i got that now i will do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following thing :

In your Activity1

Override onClickListener of button, and call AsyncTask

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener( new onClickListener(){
//Call asynctask
YourAsyncTask yastask=new YourAsyncTask();
yastask.execute();
});
```

**YourAsyncTask** must be like this :

```
private class LoginOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 boolean isAuthorized;
//for showing background process is running use progress dialog

 private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

 //Here you have to consume your web service, 
 //Send username and password as parameter to your .net service and depending upon     authorization process, you will send results
 //for example if user is authorzed, you send some boolean type as result. or say simply username if he/she is an authorized user.

 isAuthorized=Result;
 return null;
 }


 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

 try
      {
           if(Dialog.isShowing())
           {
               Dialog.dismiss();

           }

 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {

 }

if(isAuthorized)
    //Start Other Activity
else
   //Display error message using Toast.

 }


 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
      Dialog.setMessage("Authenticating.....");
     Dialog.show();

 // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog

 }


 }
```